# How to choose route in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have global.ascx with three routes

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");



        routes.MapRoute(
           "TestRoute",
           "{id}",
           new { controller = "Product", action = "Index3", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
           new { id = @"\d+" } //one or more digits only, no alphabetical characters
       );

        routes.MapRoute(
           "TestCatalogRoute",
           "{id}",
           new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "RsvpForm", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            //new { controller = "Product", action = "Index2", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );


    }
```

When I enter url:

```
http://mydomain.com/
```

It uses "TestCatalogRoute" route, but I want "Default" route T.T

How to:

- with url: `http://mydomain.com` it uses "Default" route
- with url: `http://mydomain.com/1` it uses "TestRoute" route (It's already done!)
- with url: `http://mydomain.com/abc` it uses "TestCatalogRoute" route

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `id = UrlParameter.Optional` for `TestCatalogRoute` then

Answer (score 3):

Change the order of your routes. The routehandler will validate each route, first one that matches will get picked. So if you put the second one last, you should be fine?

Comment: It's good, but i thinks "Default" route shout be locate at last :)

Comment: You're right, and zerkms is the best answer. You're second route is useless without the id parameter so it shouldn't be optional.

Answer (score 1):

I can recomend using Routing Debugger to debug your route easy to use.

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx